# eigenfunction of schrodinger operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schrodinger-operators

For a Schrodinger operator $H=\Delta+V$, with very nice potential, such as in Schwartz class, and if $0$ is an eigenvalue, furthermore, there exists a positive eigenfunction associated with 0, then my question is can we prove that actually 0 is the smallest eigenvalue and the dimension of the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ with $\lambda=0$ is 1?